# WMTS from GeoServer to OpenLayers is Unknown TILEMATRIX X

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers, tiles, wmts

I tryed use default WMTS layer with GeoServer source.
Code looks like that:

```
      var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857');
      var projectionExtent = projection.getExtent();
      var size = ol.extent.getWidth(projectionExtent) / 256;
      var resolutions = new Array(10);
      var matrixIds = new Array(10);
      for (var z = 1; z < 10; ++z) {
          // generate resolutions and matrixIds arrays for this WMTS
          resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
          matrixIds[z] = z;
      }
      const wmts_osm = new ol.source.WMTS({
        url: 'http://local:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts',
              layer: 'workspace:test_CFD_layerset',
              matrixSet: 'geogrid4CFD',
              format: 'image/png',

              tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
                        origin: ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
                        resolutions: resolutions,
                        matrixIds: matrixIds
              }),
              style: 'default',
              wrapX: true
      })

      var wmtslayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: wmts_osm
      })
```

but WMTS requests in Chrome debuger are 400:

```
<ExceptionText>Unknown TILEMATRIX 6</ExceptionText>
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matrix is almost certainly not called just `6`, if you look in the GetCapabilities response from GeoServer you will see a list of available matrix sets like this:

```
<TileMatrixSetLink>
<TileMatrixSet>EPSG:4326</TileMatrixSet>
<TileMatrixSetLimits>
<TileMatrixLimits>
<TileMatrix>EPSG:4326:0</TileMatrix>
<MinTileRow>0</MinTileRow>
<MaxTileRow>0</MaxTileRow>
<MinTileCol>1</MinTileCol>
<MaxTileCol>1</MaxTileCol>
</TileMatrixLimits>
<TileMatrixLimits>
<TileMatrix>EPSG:4326:1</TileMatrix>
<MinTileRow>0</MinTileRow>
<MaxTileRow>0</MaxTileRow>
<MinTileCol>2</MinTileCol>
<MaxTileCol>2</MaxTileCol>
</TileMatrixLimits>
...
```

So once you know what your `TileMatrixSet` is called (possibly `geogrid4CFD` in your code) you can work out what the `TileMatrix`s are called, in this example `EPSG:4326:0`.

So it looks like you need to append the tile set name and a : to the number you store in `matrixIds`.

Comment: Yes. just change ``` matrixIds[z] = z ``` -> ``` matrixIds[z] ='geogrid4CFD:' z  ```